# Pygame swap position of two tiles

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a sliding puzzle game using pygame and I'm having an issue with swapping two tiles. Currently I want to check if the desired tile (tilemap[tileh][tilew] in this case has a blank tile (id 0) adjacent to it. If it does i would like the value of these two tiles to swap. Here is what I have currently:

```
tilew = 1
tileh = 1
adjacent = [tilemap[tileh][tilew+1],tilemap[tileh][tilew-1],tilemap[tileh+1][tilew],tilemap[tileh-1][tilew]]
for x in adjacent:
    if x == 0:
        x = tilemap[tilew][tileh]
        tilemap[tilew][tileh] = 0
```

However rather than assigning the x tilemap position the new value, it assigns the tilemap value of x to be equal to the new value. This method also does not work if the tile is not the centre tile, and instead at the edge.

I would appreciate any help either fixing my current issue, or another solution that will not have the centre / edge issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would solve your problem, but if you want to try and swap two tiles, wouldn't you need a placeholder for this?

Like when using bubble sort, you have a "temporary" placeholder to store a certain value in so that a swap could be made.

Comment: I'm not sure this would help. The issue is x is being assigned as the value of tilemap[tilew][tileh+1], such as 4, instead of 'tilemap[tilew][tileh+1]', therefore the line  x = tilemap[tilew][tileh] is essentially saying 0 = 4 for example.